# How can I put a spring application on website?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I have basic question. I have some application for example this app use spring boot. When I start this app I can use it in my browser under:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp
```

Lets say that I have bought a domain name:

```
www.myApp.pl
```

What shall be done to deploy my app on this server?

Comment: You will use a DNS, there are all that configuration to run using `www.myApp.pl` when you bought a domain there are a manual to follow I'm sure

Answer (score 4):

You can deploy your Spring Boot application on Heroku platform.

The following document is useful for the deploying stages : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku

Then you can follow these steps to customize domain name : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to publish an Spring Boot app on internet is using AWS Elastik Beanstalk

This youtube video will guide you on that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBZXxWY0d04

Then AWS has a service named Route53 that will help you to connect that server with your domain.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I found a great video on how to make your application on Internet from any device. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFjYzhkEBys

Basically you can configure port-forwarding in your router settings and there you go! I was so excited to find this solution, because all you need is your internet provider and technical capacity

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32539207)